# Batch find lowest, higest and mean number. Set as variable

Tags: variables, batch-file, for-loop

so I was wondering if someone could help me, my code works just fine, does the job as it should, just looking for a more efficient way to obtain the same results. One part of the batch file is to "ping" an IP. But I don't actually want to ping anything, so I'm faking the ping screen.

```
:: Generate fake latency for ping results
:GenerateLatency
CLS
:: Get a starting range for the latency between 150-225ms
SET /A LatencyStarting=%RANDOM%%%76+150
:: +30 variable range from LatencyStarting to give semi-believable results
SET /A Latency1=%RANDOM%%%31+%LatencyStarting%
SET /A Latency2=%RANDOM%%%31+%LatencyStarting%
:: IF statement(s) to check that no 2 numbers are the same
IF "%Latency2%"=="%Latency1%" GOTO :GenerateLatency
SET /A Latency3=%RANDOM%%%31+%LatencyStarting%
IF "%Latency3%"=="%Latency1%" GOTO :GenerateLatency
IF "%Latency3%"=="%Latency2%" GOTO :GenerateLatency
:: Find lowest latency
IF %Latency1% LSS %Latency2% (
    IF %Latency1% LSS %Latency3% (
    SET LowestLatency=%Latency1%
    )
)
IF %Latency2% LSS %Latency1% (
    IF %Latency2% LSS %Latency3% (
    SET LowestLatency=%Latency2%
    )
)
IF %Latency3% LSS %Latency1% (
    IF %Latency3% LSS %Latency2% (
    SET LowestLatency=%Latency3%
    )
)
:: Find highest latency
IF %Latency1% GTR %Latency2% (
    IF %Latency1% GTR %Latency3% (
    SET GreatestLatency=%Latency1%
    )
)
IF %Latency2% GTR %Latency1% (
    IF %Latency2% GTR %Latency3% (
    SET GreatestLatency=%Latency2%
    )
)
IF %Latency3% GTR %Latency1% (
    IF %Latency3% GTR %Latency2% (
    SET GreatestLatency=%Latency3%
    )
)
:: Find the Mean Latency
SET /A AddedLatency=%Latency1%+%Latency2%+%Latency3%
SET /A MeanLatency=%AddedLatency%/3
```

6 IF statements, followed by a nested IF on each. I'm sure this could all be done by using a FOR loop or two, but the thing about that it is, I can't seem to grasp the basic concept of FOR loops. Delims, tokens might as well be Japanese to me.

Comment: Have you tried anything using `for`?

Comment: Yes, FOR /L those are the easiest for me (well anyone I suppose) it's just when we get into the FOR /F I get flustered.

Comment: Okay, so please share your attempts and describe where you are stuck, by editing your post; otherwise your question is off topic here in Stack Overflow (the post as it is now would perhaps fit better to Code Review, I think);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's simplify looking for the greatest value as follows:

```
:: Find highest latency
Set /A "GreatestLatency=Latency1"
If %Latency2% GTR %GreatestLatency% set /A "GreatestLatency=Latency2"
If %Latency3% GTR %GreatestLatency% set /A "GreatestLatency=Latency3"
```

Next, make above a [`for` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html) (don't forget to place [`SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion`](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) somewhere ahead your script:

```
:: Find highest latency
Set /A "GreatestLatency=Latency1"
for /L %%G in (2 1 3) do ( 
    If !Latency%%G! GTR !GreatestLatency! set "GreatestLatency=!Latency%%G!"
)
```

Comment: Ah, assume the first variable is the greatest, than check against the other two against that. much simpler than all my IF statements. Thank you